# Android NoClassDefFoundError vs. Error generating final archive: Found duplicate file for APK:

Tags: java, android, jar, dependencies, libgdx

I am attempting to launch an Android project in Eclipse that depends on another regular Java project which in turn has a JAR included in its build path. If I launch the Android project, I get a `NoClassDefFoundError` when the source code from the regular Java project uses code from the JAR. I have tried the solution of putting the JAR in the libs folder and adding it to my build path (and even moving it to the top), however this in turn generates the `Error generating final archive: Found duplicate file for APK: libs/gdx.jar` error. Visually:

```
[JAR not in Android path]: Android Project -> Java Project -> Jar -> NoClassDefFoundError
[JAR in Android path]:     Android Project -> Java Project -> JAR -> Duplicate file for APK Error
```

Specifically, this is a LibGDX project. I made a JAR that encapsulates some common LibGDX functionality I'll be reusing. When I run my Desktop project (with no changes to its build path) it runs perfectly, but the Android project fails. How do I properly include this JAR in my Android project?

Comment: Are you using Eclipse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I discovered the source of the problem:

1. The console was reading out `bad class file magic (CAFEBABE)` when it hit the included JAR/project when compiling with Android. This caused it not to be included in the build
2. When the app went to use the referenced JAR, it couldn't find it, however the *Desktop* program did not produce that same error output and *could* use the JAR.
3. The issue was that I had moved the code to a different Java project which was set up to use Java 7 by default, and Android only supports Java 6, and the original project it had migrated from was set up to use Java 6 (as configured by LibGDX's setup wizard). This explains why the project worked on my Desktop (which can do Java 7) but not the Android.
4. When I recompiled the JAR with Java 6, Android was able to resolve the JAR and include it in the project.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the JAR is checked as "exported": right-click on the project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Order and Export tab -> Make sure the JAR entry (or "Android Private Libraries") is checked.

I have a similar setup (with a project containing Libgdx-dependent "common" code that I share among my Libgdx projects).  However, instead of building a JAR, I just include the project directly.  (Java Build Path -> Projects tab -> Add...).  I had to include my CommonProject explicitly in all of the Libgdx project (common, desktop, android, etc), it wasn't "inheriting" from the Libgdx common project into the android one.  You may have to do something similar with your JAR file.

Comment: Yes, it's marked as exported. The problem persists. I will try manually linking all the projects like that instead.

Comment: I included the project in the build path, checked it, moved it to the top, and the problem is still there.

Comment: @GraphicsMuncher try not exporting android dependencies and android private libaries

Comment: @VikalpJain Revmoing the Android private libraries causes the app to error out as soon as it launches (ClassLoader), and removing the dependencies does nothing.

Comment: @graphicmucher: can you upload the snapshots of your expoted java dependencies and the exported dependencies of your main project